# Set button inside edittext android

Tags: android

this is my layout image. I want to set the Edittext's text don't wrap on button. How i set this.
    This is link for image open
    http://screencast.com/t/fgD5a84HMC

```
 This is my layout

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_headerbar" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="36dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="0.1"
        >
    </Button>

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_cancel" >
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/icn_inputclear"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @kelsi Can we access image from your system? please copy and paste it.

Comment: sory for that : http://screencast.com/t/fgD5a84HMC

Answer (score 0):

check this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="36dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="-1"
        android:shadowRadius="0.1"
        >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12dip" >
    </EditText>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
         >
    </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButton1"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

set the background image I just getting error so remove that code of line

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply but i want the imageButton5 inside edittext but this set the right of edittext.

Comment: can you upload the image in the question